# It is possible having MySQL server and MariaDB server together in the same Ubuntu 14.04 using official packages?

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-14.04, mariadb

**It is possible having MySQL server and MariaDB server together in the same Ubuntu 14.04 using official packages?**

I want to have both servers running in the same machine, using different listening ports. Would it be possible using official packages of software repositories?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not using official packages. They would attempt to use the same configuration files and data directories, which would result in a crash at best, and data loss at worst.

If you really want to do this, try using containers.